# jQuery: How do I make a manipulation dependant on the DOM prior to insertion, relative to the insertion?

Tags: jquery

I want to make it so that I `.append()` to a value based on the status of some other element relative to the place I'm inserting into the dom. What I really want is a trigger that fires **after** the element has been inserted.

```
$("#foo").append(
  $('<div />').load( function () {
    if ( $(this).find('.foo') {
      $(this).append( "<span>foobar</span>" )
    }
  } )
);
```

In the above example I use `.load()` as pseudo-code to do what I want -- It doesn't work for me. Here, `.load()` executes the function and sets `$(this)` to the element I attached the event too.

Comment: So if you're appending to `#foo`, you want to use some logic to decide what to append based on the current content of `#foo`. Is that right?

Comment: right. with the logic dependent on where the div will placed.

Comment: But the question of "where" has been answered since you are calling `append()` on `#foo`. The content is going to be added after the existing content of `#foo`. I guess I would need to see some markup and some detail regarding a specific case. Add that to your question, and I can give it a look tomorrow.

Comment: Right, the question has been answered -- to the reader. However, the element is yet unattached to `#foo`: until the call to `.append()` completes the content being created does not know where its destination is. This is why I was asking for something like a trigger for jQuery attachment.

Comment: Sorry if I seem a little obtuse, but I just want to clarify that you know that the content will be going *somewhere* inside `#foo`, but the logic will determine exactly *where* inside `#foo` it should go. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like maybe you just need to back some of your code out of the `append()`. Right now, the argument sent to `append()` isn't valid.

Based on your example, I guess I'm just not sure why you don't do something like this:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');

if( $foo.find('.foo').length ) {
    $foo.append("<span>foobar</span>");
}
```

Please provide more info if this doesn't meet your need.